# Angular14: How to query a form component with ContentChild

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-content-projection

Let's say I want to put any form component to a wrapper form field component. How can I query any form component that can use formControl directives.

The wrapper component will be used like this.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field',
  template: `
    <label >{{label}}</label>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="error-message">{{error}}</div>

  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class FormFieldComponent {

  @ContentChild(IDontKnowWhatToPutHere) formComponent: IDontKnowWhatToPutHere 

  @Input() label!: string;

  error: string = "";

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.listenToErrorsAndSetError(this.formComponent.control)
  }
}
```

Then, this component can be used like this.

```html
...
<form-field label="myLabel">
  <input formControlName="myControlName">
</form-field>
<form-field label="myLabel2">
  <custom-multiselect formControlName="myControlName2"></custom-multiselect>
</form-field>
...
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all form elements by NgControl directive. But ContentChild decorator will select only the first one element. Use ContentChildren to access all of them.

Example:

```
@ContentChild(NgControl) formComponent: NgControl
```